# grep first number in a file

Tags: text-processing, grep, variable, numeric-data

I have a file with the following string:

333.222.2.1

What is the command in Linux to grep just 333 and set it to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Short ***cut*** command approach:

```
v=$(cut -d'.' -f1 filename)
echo $v
333
```

---

Or with ***grep***:

```
v=$(grep -o '^[0-9]*' filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are no other lines in the file, `var=$(awk -F. '{print $1}' filename)` will do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
grep -oE '^\s*[0-9]+' filename
```

Assigning to a variable:

```
var=$(grep -oE '^\s*[0-9]+' filename.txt)
```

Comment: var=$(grep -oE '^\s*[0-9]+' filename.txt)